# Oracle regex if trimmed string contains solely L or P letters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following column (lock_reason) and I would like to obtain the desired_output column.
Logic: if, trimming everything but letters, the resulting string consists solely of L or P characters, then 'X' else NULL.

```
LOCK_REASON       DESIRED_OUTPUT
--------------------------------
2P, Q                       NULL
R                           NULL
3A, 2B, 7Z                  NULL
L, 9P                          X
P                              X
7A, 2L                      NULL
P, L                           X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove all non-alphabetical characters and then check if the remaining string is only `L` or `P` characters then:

```sql
SELECT lock_reason,
       CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( REGEXP_REPLACE( lock_reason, '[^A-Z]' ), '^[LP]+$' )
       THEN 'X'
       END AS desired_output
FROM   table_name;
```

If your string is composed of comma-space separated terms with an optional digit and then an alphabetic character then you could use:

```sql
SELECT lock_reason,
       CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( lock_reason, '^(\d*[LP], )*\d*[LP]$' )
       THEN 'X'
       END AS desired_output
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( LOCK_REASON ) AS
SELECT '2P, Q'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'R'          FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '3A, 2B, 7Z' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'L, 9P'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P'          FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '7A, 2L'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'P, L'       FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | LOCK_REASON | DESIRED_OUTPUT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2P, Q |  |
> | R |  |
> | 3A, 2B, 7Z |  |
> | L, 9P | X |
> | P | X |
> | 7A, 2L |  |
> | P, L | X |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5b7905991ca10b07add51c53d028177)*

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a combination of

- `regexp_replace` (to remove everything that isn't a letter) and
- `translate` (to remove `P` and `L` from what remained).

The rest is easy (`case`, right?).

```
SQL> select lock_reason,
  2    case when translate(regexp_replace(lock_reason, '[^[:alpha:]]', null), '#PL', '#') is null then 'X'
  3         else null
  4    end as result
  5  from test;

LOCK_REASON  RESULT
------------ ----------
2P, Q
R
3A, 2B, 7Z
L, 9P        X
P            X
7A, 2L
P, L         X

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```